# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to use BigQuery from google.cloud

Tags: python, google-bigquery

So when I run my import statement in my python script, I'd get a ModuleNotFoundError.

```
    from google.cloud import bigquery
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

I've been following https://www.getcensus.com/blog/how-to-hack-it-extracting-data-from-google-bigquery-with-python-2 and I've ran a

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
```

which still hasn't worked

I've tried installing a few other packages from google, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Are package installations _generally_ working for you? If someone came to me in the office with this problem and had tried what you have, my first thought would be that it's a path issue.  If you generally don't have trouble with installing third party libraries that's less likely to be true. Second question: how are you running python? Just `python3` in the terminal? In an iPython shell? Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a [virtual env](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) in your current project, then install the following package with `pip` :

`requirements.txt` file

```
google-api-python-client==2.70.0
```

In your virtual env, run the following command :

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then you will be able to import the expected elements from the library :

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

Check your Python version and use `Python 3`.